# Não visualizar PDF dentro do navegador

Tags: html, pdf

Eu tenho a seguinte ancora:

```
   <a href="http://localhost/refazer/uploads/0503-14.pdf">Conteúdo</a>
```

Ao clicar neste link automaticamente o navegador reconhece que é PDF e o visualiza. Como abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contrário disto, queria que quando fosse disparado o click sobre o link o navegador começasse a fazer o download do mesmo.

Comment: Qual a sua linguagem do lado do servidor?

Answer (score 7):

A resposta comum para isto é que você deve mudar o link para em vêz de ser um ficheiro usar uma página do lado do servidor (PHP por exemplo) e configurar o http header para forçar o download.

Porém em HTML5 existe [um novo atributo](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) `download`que faz isso mesmo, ou seja diz ao browser que esse link é para fazer download. No valor desse novo campo pode inserir o nome do ficheiro ou não defenir para usar o que está no link.

```
 <a href="http://localhost/refazer/uploads/0503-14.pdf" download>Conteúdo</a>
                                                        ^------^
```

Exemplo com um valor no `download`que faz override do nome do ficheiro que estava no `href` seria:

```
<a href="http://localhost/refazer/uploads/0503-14.pdf" download="ficheiro0503.pdf">Conteúdo</a>
```

**Nota:** Os browsers estão aos poucos a integrar as novas especificações do HTML5. Hoje isto não funciona em todos os browsers, daqui a uns meses, ou para o próximo ano, isto deve ser a prática comum.

Comment: Poderia me explicar melhor essa parte: "A resposta comum para isto é que você deve mudar o link para em vêz de ser um ficheiro usar uma página do lado do servidor (PHP por exemplo) e configurar o http header para forçar o download."

Comment: @Luitame, quando o servidor envia dados para o browser tem um "cabeçalho" (header) que ajuda o browser a saber o que fazer com a informação. Nesse header, e dependendo de que linguagem tem do lado do servidor, pode especificar que é um ficheiro para gravar, e não para abrir. Daí a minha pergunta nos comentários acima: `Qual é a sua linguagem do lado do servidor?`

Comment: A linguagem é PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

A forma de efetuar no PHP é bem simples

```
<?php

$file_url = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);

?>
```

No lugar do $_GET['file'] pode colocar o nome do arquivo, ou uma variavel da página.
Embora o HTML5 tenha evoluido muita coisa, nem todos usuários evoluiram junto com a
tecnologia. Sempre haverá pessoas com navegadores antigos. Isso levará anos para sumir.

O tipo "application/octet-stream" indica que devera baixar parte por parte (continuo) e codificação "Binary" indica que seguira o padrão binário para baixar, desta forma não danificando o arquivo final.