# Baixar View em vez de exibi-la

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

ha alguma forma de ao invés de eu retornar uma view e exibi-la na tela para o usuário, eu a retorne mas ao invés de exibi-la eu salve o arquivo .html no computador?
O código é o seguinte:

```
return View("~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", model);
```

mas ele retorna a view e a exibe para o usuário, eu queria uma forma que baixa-se o arquivo html em vez de exibi-la, é possível fazer isso de alguma forma?

Comment: Tipo [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15841/n%C3%A3o-visualizar-pdf-dentro-do-navegador)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
   ViewData.Model = model;
   using (var sw = new StringWriter())
   {

    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, 
                                 viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, 
                                 TempData, 
                                 sw);

    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

  }
}
```

e no teu `controller`:

```
return File(encoding.GetBytes(RenderRazorViewToString("Item", model)),"text/html");
```

Talvez tenha que mudar o nome do `path` (caminho) para que funcione, faça um  `debug` caso não funcione, e veja em qual `path` está procurando a `View` que foi passsada como parâmetro.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou :D

Comment: de nada! 

Ja agora, Virgilio, porque editaste a resposta? nao se pode escrever em portugues de portugal? nao posso tratar uma pessoa por tu? curiosidade...